# Existe alguma maneira de fazer requisições assíncronas à uma url pelo PHP?

Tags: php

Preciso fazer várias requisições (umas 200 requisições) para uma url externa, porém não quero que o php "espere" pelo término da requisição.

Lembrando que eu quero evitar utilizar funções como `exec` e coisas tais que rodem na linha de comando, por conta de servidores compartilhados não terem suporte a tais operações.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer requisições assíncronas à uma url pelo PHP?

Comment: sim, com sockets :) Seu PHP precisa ser servido pelo servidor HTTPD, ou pode rodar diretamente?

Comment: Que pergunta difícil: O que é HTTPD?

Comment: Http Daemon (é o servidor de páginas). Normalmente essa sigla é usada em linux, na verdade como eu usei a palavra servidor, devia ter tirado o D do final. Foi uma falha na minha edição do comentário.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A biblioteca [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/5.3/clients.html) em suas mais recentes versões tem suporte para requisições assíncronas.

Exemplo retirado da documentação.

```
$requests = [
    $client->createRequest('GET', 'http://httpbin.org'),
    $client->createRequest('DELETE', 'http://httpbin.org/delete'),
    $client->createRequest('PUT', 'http://httpbin.org/put', ['body' => 'test'])
];

$options = [];

// Cria pool. 
$pool = new Pool($client, $requests, $options);
//envia todas as requisições e quando elas terminarem chama o callback complete.
Pool::send($client, $requests, [
    'complete' => function (CompleteEvent $event) {
           echo 'Completed request to ' . $event->getRequest()->getUrl() . "\n";
           echo 'Response: ' . $event->getResponse()->getBody() . "\n\n";
     }
]);

//continue seu código aqui.
```

Nesse caso todas as requisições serão executadas em paralelo sem bloquear

Comment: Eu já cheguei a testar algumas coisas do Guzzle referente a `async request`, porém sem sucesso. Eu vou testar mais e ver se consigo algum resultado. De qualquer maneira, eu estou agradecido pela resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Apenas como complemento da reposta do @ViniciusZaramella, onde ele cita as
requisições do `Guzzle\Http`.

## Explanação sobre o Assincronismo do Guzzle

Em relação ao assincronismo referente às requisições do Guzzle,  percebi que o mesmo, ao utilizar a classe `Pool` na verdade envia várias requisições de uma vez em `background`, tendo por tanto suas respostas assincronamente.

No caso, se fizessemos uma requisição com o `Guzzle`, normalmente, sem usar o `Pool`, dentro de um for de 0 a 200, cara requisição aguardaria a resposta  da outra para realizar uma requisição.

Exemplo:

```
  $guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

  for ($i = 0; $i  < 200; $i++)
  {
       $guzzle->get('http://httpbin.org/get', ['query' => ['i' => $i]]);
  }
```

Já no caso do `Pool`, as requisições são enviadas "de uma vez" - de acordo com a configuração que você na opção  `concurrency`, que é o número de requisições feitas por vez na fila.

```
$requests = function () {

    $guzzle = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    for ($i = 0; $i  < 200; $i++)
    {
          yield $guzzle->get('http://httpbin.org/get', ['query' => ['i' => $i]]);
    }
};


$pool = new Pool($guzzle, $requests(), [
    'concurrency' => 50, // envia de 30 em 30,
    'rejected' => function ($exception, $index)
    {

    },

    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index)
    {

    }
]);


$poll->promise()->wait();
```

Realizei testes similares aos dois casos. O resultado obtido foi que, no caso semelhante ao primeiro exemplo, demorou-se 45 a 50 segundos uma requisição (o suficiente para dar aquele erro de limite de tempo do PHP).  Já no segundo caso, apenas de 5 a 7 segundos foram utilizados no tempo de execução.

Então, realmente é um método eficaz.

## Outro Assincronismo

Antes de ser publicada a resposta do Vinícius, eu tinha achado na internet de fazer requisições assíncronas com o PHP. Porém, ao realizar tal operação, **O PHP não esperará pela resposta**, mas apenas fará a requisição enquanto o código será executado normalmente até o final.

```
function async_request($method, $url, $params, array $headers = [])
{

    $method = strtoupper($method);

    $sendData = in_array($method, array('PUT', 'POST'));

    $data = http_build_query($params);

    $parts = parse_url($url) + [
        'port'  => 80,
        'path'  => '/',
    ];

    $headers += [
        'Content-Type'   => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Host'           => $parts['host'],
        'Content-Length' => !$sendData ? 0 : strlen($data),
        'Connection'     => 'Close'
    ];

    $path = !$sendData ? $parts['path'] . '?' . $data : $parts['path'];

    $output_header = sprintf('%s %s HTTP/1.1', $method, $path) . "\r\n";

    foreach ($headers as $name => $value)
    {
        foreach((array) $value as $v)
        {
            $output_header .= "$name: $v\r\n";
        }
    }

    $output_header .= "\r\n";

    $handle = @fsockopen($parts['host'], $parts['port'], $_errno, $_errstr, 30);

    if ($handle === false)
    {
        throw new \RuntimeException($_errstr);
    }

    fwrite($handle, $output_header);

    if ($sendData) fwrite($handle, $data);

    fclose($handle);

    return $output_header;

}
```

Você pode fazer o teste nessa função da seguinte forma:

```
#index.php

assync_request('GET', 'http://localhost/target.php', []);

echo 'terminou';

#target.php

sleep(5);
file_put_contents('gato.txt', "Meow!!!\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

Quando você fizer a requisição, perceberá que a palavra `'terminou'` será exibida imediatamente. E depois de 5 segundos, é que o arquivo `gato.txt` será criado. Isso acontece porque o php executou um socket no backgroud, que ficou responsável pela requisição de `target.php`.

Era essa a ideia que eu tinha inicialmente a respeito do assincronismo, mas de qualquer forma a resposta do @ViniciusZaramella me atendeu melhor.

Comment: Tem um erro em `async_request`, faltou o envio do POST assim: `fwrite($fp, $out); fwrite($fp, $post_string);`

Comment: Corrigi a função toda. Fiz testes aqui e deu tudo certinho :D

Comment: Ficou ótimo! Fiz uma edição, pra permitir enviar dados somente com POST ou PUT =)

Comment: Ah, sim. Entendi. Valeu :D, criei um [gist](https://gist.github.com/wallacemaxters/b39c9e069a2e71e71bea) também para poder lembrar dessa função.

Answer (score -3):

Uma rotina antiga que desenvolvi:

```
class Background
{

    /*
    $cmd -> A linha de comando a executar.
    $opt -> Opção de parâmetros para o ambiente onde executa o script.
    */
    public static function Call($cmd, $opt = 'start')
    {

        if (stripos(php_uname('s'), 'windows') !== false) {
            /*
            Condições de parâmetros para ambiente Windows.
            */
            switch ($opt) {
                default:
                case 'start':
                    $prefix = 'start /B '; // Esse aqui é o padrão, pois é compatível com as versões mais recentes do Windows.
                    $sufix = '';
                    break;
                case 'nul':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' > NUL 2> NUL';
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            /*
            Opções para ambiente *nix. (isso inclui os-x)
            Normalmente o sufixo ` &` é compatível com diversas distribuições Linux. Esse parâmetro diz ao sistema operacional executar em background.
            */
            switch ($opt) {
                default:
                case '&':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' &';
                    break;
                case 'dev-null':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';
                    break;
            }
        }

        exec(sprintf('%s%s%s', $prefix, $cmd, $sufix));

        return null;
    }

}

define('PHP_PATH', '/local/do/binario/php');

echo 'start '.microtime(true);
Background::Call(PHP_PATH.' "/local/de/um/arquivo.php"');
Background::Call(PHP_PATH.' "/local/de/um/arquivo.php"');
Background::Call(PHP_PATH.' "/local/de/um/arquivo.php"');
echo PHP_EOL.'end '.microtime(true);
```

**arquivo.php**

```
<?php

/*
Fecha o output, ou seja, faz com que o script que invocou, não fique esperando por uma resposta.
*/
fclose(STDOUT);

/*
Daqui em diante, pode fazer o que bem entender.
Claro, esteja ciente de que tudo aqui está sendo executado em ambiente CLI (Command Line Interface).

Vamos fazer um exemplo para simular e testar se está funcionando.
*/

file_put_contents('background.txt', 'start '.microtime(true).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
sleep(5); // espera 5 segundos
file_put_contents(BASE_DIR.'background.txt', 'end '.microtime(true).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

**Sobre a rotina de execução assíncrona**

Não há um controle dos processos. Basicamente é enviado um comando de execução pela função `exec()`, que combinado com alguns parâmetros ignora o retorno de uma resposta. Perfazendo assim, execuções assíncronas.

As combinações variam de acordo com o ambiente, portanto, esteja ciente de que não basta apenas copiar o código e pensar que vai funcionar como mágica.

No método `Call()` da classe `Background`, basta adicionar parâmetros novos se necessário.

Exemplo:

```
            /*
            Opções para ambiente *nix. (isso inclui os-x)
            Normalmente o sufixo ` &` é compatível com diversas distribuições Linux. Esse parâmetro diz ao sistema operacional executar em background.
            */

            switch ($opt) {
                default:
                case '&':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' &';
                    break;
                case 'dev-null':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';
                    break;
                case 'dev-null2':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' /dev/null 2>&1 &';
                    break;
                case 'outro-nome-como-quiser':
                    $prefix = '';
                    $sufix = ' /algum/comando/diferente/que/funcione/num/ambiente/especifico';
                    break;
            }
```

O script é simples, limpo, fácil de entender. Não depende de bibliotecas terceiras.

Comment: a pergunta deixou explicito que não queria soluções envolvendo exec. "Lembrando que eu quero evitar utilizar funções como exec"

Comment: Desnecessário negativar pois a frase diz "quero evitar" e não exatamente quer dizer que não seja uma possibilidade. Além do mais, o motivo de evitar é devido a ambientes como hosts compartilhados que podem negar o uso de execuções por command line. Mas muitos hosts permitem com certas restrições, como por exemplo, não permitir acessar funções específicas do Sistema Operacional, mas permite executar coisas simples como o PHP, fazer agendamentos cron, acessar compressor de dados como zlib, rar, etc.